# No existing whitelist file found in Corda

Tags: corda

I am trying to add a class to Corda whitelist.

```
class ExamplePluginSerial : SerializationWhitelist {
    override val whitelist: List<Class<*>> get() = listOf(TransactionBuilder::class.java)
}
```

Have also written a file in META-INF.services called

```
net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationWhitelist
```

The following is the code there

```
# Register a ServiceLoader service extending for 3rd party classes extending from net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationWhitelist 
com.example.plugin.ExamplePluginSerial
```

When I am building this project using

```
gradlew clean deployNodes
```

I am getting this

```
No existing whitelist file found.
```

Can anyone please explain the cause of error?

Comment: Can you provide the full filepath for the META-INF.services file?

Comment: C:\Users\*****\Desktop\cordapp-example\cordapp-example\kotlin-source\src\main\resources\META-INF

Comment: I'm not sure based on your answer whether you got it right :( You need a file called `net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationWhitelist` in the directory `/src/main/resources/META-INF/services`. Is that what you have?

Comment: yes. src\main\resources\META-INF\services

Comment: I have created a file called net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationWhitelist. Is there a method to generate this file ?

Comment: No, you create it manually. Hmm. When you say you get that error, does it cause any issues, or does the bootstrapping complete successfully?

Comment: While bootstrapping it is showing 'no existing whitelist file is found' and bootstrapping correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error. It's a standard message printed as part of the bootstrapping process. You should see the following sequence of messages:

```
No existing whitelist file found.
Calculating whitelist for current installed CorDapps..
CorDapp whitelist generated in <path>/build/nodes/whitelist.txt
Updating whitelist
```

This means that your whitelist has been picked up correctly.

Comment: Another question. how many states can we create in one corda project ? is there any maximum number ?

Comment: No, there is no limit (except perhaps a Java-specific limit such as max JAR size or max classpath size?).